# Is there any wordpress plugin to upload images and captions to multiple pages once

Tags: php

Hi I have a couple of pages that need the same images and captions, is there a wordpress plugin that would allow this on 1 upload?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just insert the image from the media library?

Comment: i could try, I am new to wordpress so hope this can do it

Comment: You should be able to - you don't have to upload an image each time to insert it.  Just pick it and go.

Comment: cool, what about the caption?

Comment: I believe you can go into Media Library -> edit and set a standard caption, alt text, etc which will be set whenever you insert it (from that point on).